# Filtrar elementos do Select com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tenho de criar um filtro em select para realizar uma busca entre vários resultados do select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="grupo">
<!-- class="borda select2_single form-control comboauto" -->
    <select name="id_projeto" id="id_projeto" class="borda select2_single form-control ">
        <option value="">Selecione</option>
        <?php 
            foreach (ProjetoModel::retorna(" order by descricao") as $obj) { 
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $obj->getid() ?>" 

            <?php echo $obj->getid()==$vObject->getidProjeto()?'selected':'' ?>>
            <?php echo $obj->titulo; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função de retorno

```
public static function retorna($extra='', $vWhere=null) {
        $arr=array();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM projeto where 1=1 ';
        $sql .= self::getWhere($vWhere);
        $sql .= $extra;
        $vResult = Conexao::getInstance()->query($sql);
            while($vResult && $obj = $vResult->fetchObject()) {
                $arr[] = new ClassProjeto($obj->id, $obj->titulo, $obj->descricao, $obj->id_net, $obj->id_trafo);
            }
            return $arr;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Não deu pra entender bem o queires. Seria tipo quebra de pastas?

Comment: Apenas realizar uma busca dentro da Tag Html Select.

Comment: Porém o sistema é em php e

Comment: Ta mais essa busca vai pra onde?

Comment: Deu pra entender ali e que você ta criando este select dinamicamente pela consulta feita no banco com as opções que tem no banco. Pelo que revisei a tua pergunta, você quer que estas opções venha com filtro e não todas as opções, e isso?

Comment: Nesta parte aqui `foreach (ProjetoModel::retorna(" order by descricao")` você ta chamando a função `retorna()` com 1 parâmetro de ordenação `order by descricao` . Ache esta função e poste aqui que te passo a resposta.

Comment: Pergunta editada...

Comment: O filtro tem de ser dentro da tag html select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="grupo">
<!-- class="borda select2_single form-control comboauto" -->
<select name="id_projeto" id="id_projeto" class="borda select2_single form-control ">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <?php 
        foreach (ProjetoModel::retorna(" order by descricao", " where coluna = termo ") as $obj) { 
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $obj->getid() ?>" 

        <?php echo $obj->getid()==$vObject->getidProjeto()?'selected':'' ?>>
        <?php echo $obj->titulo; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Função do retorno:

```
public static function retorna($extra='', $vWhere=null) {
    $arr=array();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM projeto ';
    $sql .= $vWhere;
    $sql .= $extra;
    $vResult = Conexao::getInstance()->query($sql);
        while($vResult && $obj = $vResult->fetchObject()) {
            $arr[] = new ClassProjeto($obj->id, $obj->titulo, $obj->descricao, $obj->id_net, $obj->id_trafo);
        }
        return $arr;
}
```

Se atente para informar a coluna e o termo dentro do foreach. Caso queira mais filtros e so usar o `and`, ex: `where coluna = termo and coluna2 = termo2`